# 80s TV series with aliens that grow in small pods

Tags: tv, aliens, story-identification

I have a vague memory of watching a TV series as a child (UK, late 1980s or early 1990s) that featured men that looked like humans who carried around briefcases that had a bed of soil with a grid of little pods in that grew into more alien men. Memories being what they are, some of even that small bit could be pretty muddled.

I really can't remember any more than that. I can't even say if it was in color or Black and White as we had a B&W TV at the time!

The show seemed to have a vague plot of these guys trying to grow more of themselves and some agency or something trying to stop them.

Pretty vague I know, but I wonder if anyone knows what I'm on about...

Comment: What country did you watch this in? Was it in English?

Comment: Whoops, yeah it was... Dont remember if it was an English made program or not though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was it:

[image: The Invaders]

A fleshed-out description is harder to get, but there apparently was a briefcase being featured in at least one episode with alien-spores.  According to [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0612011/plotsummary):

> Courier Tom Jessup loses track of a briefcase containing something vital: spores. These organisms, properly nourished, will grow into aliens able to tolerate Earth's high oxygen content. Through mischance, Jessup loses track of the briefcase, which changes hands several times. Finally, some kids wind up with it, and meanwhile inside it the spores continue to grow, and outside it, Jessup is increasingly desperate.

The 'pods' could refer to regeneration chambers.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders) article for *The Invaders*:

> Neither the Invaders nor their planet were ever named. Their human appearance was a disguise; they were never shown in their true form except in one episode, "Genesis", in which an ill alien researcher loses his human form and is briefly seen immersed in a tank of water. Unless they receive periodic treatments in what Vincent called "regeneration chambers", which consume a great deal of electrical power, they revert to their alien form. One scene in the series showed an alien beginning to revert, filmed in soft focus and with pulsating red light.

Additional images to help remembering:

[image]

Comment: Gene Hackman is one of _them_ !!    http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xu7op0_the-invaders-the-spores-oct-17-1967_shortfilms#.UO_p2G8reuI    Doesnt look as good in colour...

Comment: Awesome, that link had the entire episode.